# Google maps dynamically added with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am using google maps to show some locations. I dont want to map on the screen the whole time, so I am using jquery to append the map as needed.

```
 $('./map').append('<script async defer 
 src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?  
key='+map_key+'&amp;libraries=visualization&amp;callback=initialize">');
```

This works for the map, however I cannot then call any methods to add markers. The page just stops loading and I cant find an error.

```
 addMarkers(makers);
```

The debugger gets to here:

```
for(var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++ ) {

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: coordinates[i].coordinates[1], lng: coordinates[i].coordinates[0]} ,
            map: map
        });
        bounds.extend({lat: coordinates[i].coordinates[1], lng: coordinates[i].coordinates[0]});
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
```

but the new google map marker is not run. The map appears fine if I comment out this method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('./map').append(<'script async="async" defer="defer" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? key='+map_key+'&amp;libraries=visualization&amp;callback=initialize">')
```

should be:

```
$('.map').append('<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? key='+map_key+'&amp;libraries=visualization&amp;callback=initialize">');
```

You added the quotation mark after the "<" making the code invalid. Also, Async and Defer do not take values and are called "boolean attributes".

Read more here:

http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html

Comment: Thanks, I moved it over from Jade code and forgot the html syntax. The quotation mark has been fixed - it was just a typo in the above. I still dont know how to handle it in this case.

Comment: did you try removing the ="async" & ="defer"; if so what were the results?

Comment: A demo of the application would be helpful

Comment: The final code is: <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='+map_key+'&amp;libraries=visualization&amp;callback=initialize" async defer ></script> which made no difference. It is hard to do a demo when you would need a your own mapkey.

Comment: Does the map appear?

Comment: Updated question. The map loads, but will not let me add markers.